# Does Yesod run more than one handler at a time (concurrently)

Tags: concurrency, race-condition, yesod

Does Yesod ever interleave the running of multiple handlers? i.e., can another Yesod handler from the same process run between Handler monad actions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Yesod will do that regularly.

Comment: I'm quite sure the book doesn't talk about that. Anyway, how are you supposed to synchronize the handlers - are persistent calls wrapped in a repeatable transaction or something? Also, at which level does the concurrency go - does the Haskell runtime context-switch in the middle of a liftIO'd action?

Comment: Warp uses the `forkIO` call for its concurrency. In other words, it's using standard Haskell concurrency primitives. The questions you're asking here are fundamental, I'd strongly recommend reading up on Haskell's threading model. Simon Marlow's book would be a great place to start.

Comment: How is concurrent access to the GHState controlled?

Comment: You're asking questions in the middle of a topic. You need to first understand the concurrency primitives GHC offers. The short answer to your question is that each thread has a separate GHState, and concurrent access is not blocked.

Comment: So, there can be multiple handlers (postMyRouteR) running concurrently, but any handler's GHState object can only be accessed by it? If I want inter-handler state, I need to properly synchronize them?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.